# How to cleanly handle/ignore (Unicode?) unprintable binary characters in AWK

Tags: regex, awk, unicode, grep

I have a file that I am trying to match with the expression /^[ \t]*r/, and I found a line (the first line) in a file that frustratingly refuses to match with either awk or egrep.  The line in question appears visually (in an editor) to indeed start with an “r”; however, when I dump the file with od -ax, I find that the file actually starts with the following:

```
0000000  o   ;   ?   r
          bbef    72bf
```

How do I deal with this?  Ideally, I want to add something to the bracket expression in my pattern such that the pattern essentially  says “starts with r” ignoring spaces, tabs and odd non-ascii junk.

Comment: That looks like a Byte Order Mark (BOM) encoded as UTF-8 (which is pointless, because UTF-8 has an unambiguous byte order anyway).

Comment: @melpomene - the file actually came from a Chinese (why I suspect a potential Unicode issue) co-worker’s Excel CSV export (Thank you very much Bill Gates for these few hours of “diversion”)...  I know I am going to see this again; so, have to find some way of cleanly dealing with it in the future.

Comment: Oh yeah, Excel likes to add BOMs where they don't belong (and corrupt imported Unicode CSV files if they don't have a pointless BOM).

Comment: Windows likes to add BOMs to differentiate with files in ANSI code pages. It's not for byte-order marking purpose

Comment: Linux likes to pretend BOMs don't exist, when it is perfectly valid (but optional) to use one as a UTF-8 signature.  In Windows, ANSI code pages existed before UTF-8 and for backward-compatibility likes to use the BOM as a signature that the file is not ANSI, but one of the UTF encodings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said in the comments, that is the BOM. I use this in awk to remove it:

```
NR==1 {sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/,"")}
```

Comment: I used: `FNR == 1 && /\xef\xbb\xbf/ { gsub(/\xef\xbb\xbf/, "") }`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use `gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/,"")` to filter out any non-ascii characters? For example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "foo \xef\xbb\xbf bar\n"}' | cat -v
foo M-oM-;M-? bar

$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "foo \xef\xbb\xbf bar\n"}' | od -ax
0000000   f   o   o  sp   o   ;   ?  sp   b   a   r  nl
           6f66    206f    bbef    20bf    6162    0a72
0000014

$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "foo \xef\xbb\xbf bar\n"}' | awk '{gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/,"")}1' | cat -v
foo  bar

$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "foo \xef\xbb\xbf bar\n"}' | awk '{gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/,"")}1' | od -ax
0000000   f   o   o  sp  sp   b   a   r  nl
           6f66    206f    6220    7261    000a
0000011
```

`[\x00-\x7F]` is the awk equivalent of `[[:ascii:]]` which some other tools apparently support.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ed... Your solution his was actually closer to what I wanted originally: *"... Ideally,  I want to add something to my bracket expression ..."* to ignore non-ascii chars, but I couldn't get the following working in my pattern: `^[ \t\x80-\xFF]*r`.   I got a run-time error & had to go with James' solution of just removing on first line. (I also tried `^[ \t[:cntrl:]]*r` -- no error but didn't work.) If you have a better idea...

Comment: Idk why your first expression would produce an error but if you're trying to match `r` preceded by zero-or-more non-ascii characters or spaces at the start of a line then try `^([^\x00-\x7F]|[[:space:]])*r` and in future if you ever want help debugging a `run-time error` or any other error then please state what the error message is.

Comment: @EdMorton : that `gsub()` only works if the entire input is `UTF-8` compliant, otherwise it leaves in unwanted bytes like this `printf $'abc\333\222xyz\371=\362_' | gawk -e 'gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/,_)^_' | od`

Answer (score 0):

this is a module i've written for just about any awk version you can imagine that can give you both `any arbitrary byte` or `any unicode character`, in the form of UTF8, regardless of your locale settings, regardless of Windows/Mac/Unix, and regardless whether you're running in byte-mode or UC-aware mode. It's tested on gawk, mawk134 and mawk-2 beta. I presume it should work fine in nawk too.

```
function fast8(c0, base3){

    c0 = ((c0 ~ /[^0-9-]/) || (base3 ~ /[0-9]/ && base3 != 10)) \
          ? any2dec(c0, base3) : c0;

    return (c0 == -999) ? "" : (c0 < 2048) ? ( (c0 < 128) ?   \
                                                            \
        sprintf("%c", (c0 % 256) - 256 * (c0 > 0) ) :     \
        sprintf("%c%c",                                 \
           -64 +  int( c0 /     64),                  \
          -128 + (     c0           % 64)) ) : (c0 < 1114112) ? ( (c0 < 65536) ? \
        sprintf("%c%c%c",                           \
           -32 +  int( c0 /   4096)      ,         \
          -128 + (int( c0 /     64) % 64),        \
          -128 + (     c0           % 64)) :     \
        sprintf("%c%c%c%c",                     \
           -16 +  int( c0 / 262144)      ,     \
          -128 + (int( c0 /   4096) % 64),    \
          -128 + (int( c0 /     64) % 64),   \
          -128 + (     c0           % 64))) \
                                           \
      : sprintf("%c", (c0 % 256) - 256)   }
```

**optional** : plug-in yourself a function `any2dec()` that can transform numbers in non-base10 to decimal integers in base10. If you need any **arbitrary byte**, take its byte decimal integer value `[0,255]`, and `subtract 256` from it.

I acknowledge this isn't anywhere close to a full and standards-compliant implementation of UTF8, but for day-to-day usage, it's very close to it. It's been tested against sprintf("%c") in gawk -e unicode mode for every code point between 0 and 1114111.

The only difference (which is intentional) lies within the UTF16 surrogate zone of U+D800 to U+DFFF. GAWK treats the space as series of repeating bytes 0 to 255. This code outputs them using same treatment as any other UC code point to UTF8 mapping.

quick benchmarking : (keep in mind this is trying to compare interpreted scripting to compiled C-binaries) looping entire 1.1mil code points of UC, 20 times :

```
4.03s gawk -e unicode mode running fast8() native sprintf("%c")
___________________
14.74s mawk 1.9.9.6
14.79s mawk 1.3.4
26.99s gawk -b byte mode
34.92s gawk -e unicode mode running fast8()

*I hereby sharing this code in public domain (for any parts not currently covered under The Unicode Consortium), and rescind any past present or future claims of ownership or copyright to the intellectual property. Unicode and the Unicode Logo are registered trademarks of Unicode, Inc. in the United States and other countries.*
```